# Strange property names in Asp Core JSON output

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net

I have a model class with a few properties named with all caps divided by underscores (e.g. `APPOINTMENT_CHECKIN_TIME`). A controller Get method returns an instance of this class. But the JSON returned to the client has parts of property names converted to lowercase, like `appointmenT_CHECKIN_TIME`. What can be causing this, and how to avoid this (e.g. make it `appointmentCheckinTime` or at least the same as original)?

Comment: What version of [tag:asp.net.core] are you using?  Are you sure you are using Json.NET and not System.Text.Json?

Answer (score 0):

Customize json property name:

```cs
[JsonPropertyName("appointmentCheckinTime")]
public DateTime APPOINTMENT_CHECKIN_TIME { get; set; }
```

Or customize the option to rename all json property names:

```cs
var serializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
    WriteIndented = true
};
jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(myObject, serializeOptions);
```

Or define a global renaming policy:

```cs
using System.Text.Json;

namespace SystemTextJsonSamples
{
    public class UpperCaseNamingPolicy : JsonNamingPolicy
    {
        public override string ConvertName(string name) =>
            name.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

```cs
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = new UpperCaseNamingPolicy(),
    WriteIndented = true
};
jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(myObject, options);
```

Resource: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0

Answer (score 0):

Add this configuration in Program.cs(.Net 6)

```
builder.Services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => { options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null; });
```